# How to open a local folder location (PLPGSQL)

Tags: postgresql, airflow, plpgsql

I have a file stored in **'./mnt/data.csv'** within an airflow instance.

I want to open the file in order to loop through the records.

In python I can simply do `open("./mnt/data.csv")` but I'm interested in how to do this in a postgres sql script.

How do I open a file in postgres procedural language PLPGSQL?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot to this in PLpgSQL. It is trusted language (in Postgres terminology), and then an user has not an access to outside Postgres. Python (PLPythonu) is untrusted language - and it allows unsecured access to outside Postgres.

Comment: Perhaps `COPY` could help; depends on the file.